# How to provide authentication in GAE web services (using restlet framework)?

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, restlet

Iam looking for a proper way of authentication for my `GAE` app.

Since I am using restlet framework for my web services I found cookies as a nice way for secure service calls. Now my doubts are:

1. What is "signing a cookie"?
2. Where to store cookie values?DB or any static class?
3. How to provide encryption for cookie?
4. What if cookie disabled in browser?

Is there any better mechanism available than cookie?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable sessions, handling cookies will be taken care of for you automatically: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions

Now, sessions are handled for all users, it's up to you to keep track who is authenticated:

1. When user logs in, [add some auth data](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to their [session](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29). This data might contain their ID an expiry time.
2. When a request comes in, look at session if this data is there and if it's still valid.
3. If valid, proceed as normal.
4. If not valid or no auth data in session, return error (in case of REST) or redirect to login page.

All this functions are usually performed in a [servlet filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). Filters handle requests before and after servlets handle request, so they give you an option to intercept a request and do some processing (like checking if request is authenticated).

Comment: I would not use a concept as sessions if you are developing a RESTful server side application. REST means that clients keep client state, and as such server side sessions are evil. Have a look at CookieSettings in RESTLet : Cookie setting provided by a server. This allows a server side application to add, modify or remove a cookie on the client.

Comment: @koma Do you mean, all client data will have to pass in the form of cookies with every request?

Comment: @koma: True, REST requests might not come from browsers, and in this case you would need to handle session cookies explicitly in your code. OTOH, how is this different then handling your own "cookie"?

Comment: @koma: I looked up RESTlet's `CookieSetting`: it does what browsers automatically do - send a cookie to server.

Comment: @Peter In the Restlet framework, one would start by writing an Authenticator that checks for credentials passed in with e.g. BASIC auth. Next you use CookieSetting  for subsequent requests.

Comment: @vivek : form data is send using query string, cookie is usually for authentication puprposes, though you have to be carefull about XSRF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)